# .net Razor alternative to PHP echo

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm new to .net MVC and Razor engine but I have been using PHP for a long time. I'm trying to do this PHP code in Razor:

```
var data = [
<?php for ($i = 0; $i < 50; ++$i) { 
  echo '[' . $i . ',' . sin($i) . ']';
  if ($i != 49)
    echo ',';
?>
],
```

I managed to do it using this, but it looks bad and complex for something so simple

```
var data = [
  @for(int i = 0; i < 50; ++i) {  
<text>[</text>@i<text>,</text>@Math.Sin(i)<text>]</text>if (i != 49) {<text>,</text>}
  } 
];
```

The problem is that `[`, `]` and `,` are confused with Razor syntax and gives syntax errors, so I had to wrap them on `<text>` tags.

Is there a simpler/nicer way to do this? Maybe something like the PHP echo.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this:

```
@String.Format("[{0},{1}]", i, Math.Sin(i))
```

And for comma you can use `String.Join()` if you create array ([String.Join Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0h8wc12c.aspx) )

Comment: Another variant of this would be `@($"[{i},{Math.Sin(i)}]")`

Answer (score 11):

A **gerenal** equivalent of echo in MVC cshtml might be:
    `@Html.Raw("SomeStringDirectlyInsideTheBrowserPageHTMLCode")`

This renders the (dynamic) string at its position where '<' and '>' no need to be HTML-coded. For example `@Html.Raw(String.Format("<div class=\"{0}\" style=\"{1}\">", myclass, mystyle))` works fine.

Note that the HTML tags rendered by `@Html.Raw(MyString)` cannot be checked by the compiler. I mean: @Html.Raw("<div ....>") cannot be closed by mere </div> because you will get an error (<div ....> is not detected by the compiler) so you must close the tag with @Html.Raw("</div>")

P.S.
In some cases this doesn't work (for example it fails within DevExpress) - use `ViewContext.Writer.Write()` or `ViewContext.Writer.WriteLine()` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Old question I know, but an alternative is to use the plaintext syntax `@:`

```
var data = [
@for (int i = 0; i < 50; ++i)
{
    @:[@i,@Math.Sin(i)]
    @(i != 49 ? "," : "")
}
];
```

Answer (score 1):

Constructing a JSON object using a view is not really the best way to go about it. You can use the native JSON support to do this directly from a controller, for example:

```
    public JsonResult SinArray()
    {
        return new JsonResult() { 
            Data = Enumerable.Range(0, 50).Select(i => new[] { i, Math.Sin(i) }), 
            JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet 
        };
    }
```

This returns

```
[[0,0],[1,0.8414709848078965],[2,0.90929742682568171],.....,[49,-0.95375265275947185]]
```

As a bonus you get the correct content-type.

Comment: Thanks this will help me in the near future. Just one question, how can I use this JsonResult directly on the View without using an Ajax call? I mean something like this: `var data = [@ViewBag.myJsonResult];`

Comment: Not sure of your exact situation, but I would probably pass it to the view using a model property. You can use [JSON.net](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) to serialize an object to a JSON string. I generally try to avoid passing complex objects to views since that implies logic living in views, and certainly invoking Math.Sin is "logic" .. and logic in views is considered a sin. :)

Comment: This is what I was trying to do  `ViewBag.myJsonResult = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(SinArray().Data);`